# Vite + pnpm Workspaces: Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module does not provide an export named '{type}'

Tags: vite, pnpm, pnpm-workspace

I am trying to setup a pnpm workspace where I have the following structure:

packages/

- `backend`
- `frontend`
- `shared`

Both the `backend` and `frontend` will consume types from `shared`. Currently, I can import types from `shared` from the `backend` package. However, when I do so in the `frontend` package I get the following console.error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module 'app-name/packages/shared/src/auth/jwtToken.dto.ts' does not provide an export named 'JwtAccessTokenType'.

This is my current `vite.config.js`:

```js
/** @type {import('vite').UserConfig} */

import { resolve } from 'path';

import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import eslint from 'vite-plugin-eslint';
import svgr from 'vite-plugin-svgr';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig(() => ({
  plugins: [
    react(),
    svgr(),
    eslint({
      include: ['./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}'],
    }),
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '~': resolve(__dirname, './src'),
    },
  },
}));
```

Do I need to configure something here so that Vite compiles correctly with a `pnpm` workspace package?

If I hover over the file that consumes the type in `frontend` I can see that Typescript infers the type correctly (probably not a TS issue).

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?